# update mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tryed this script on my local server and it's working fine but it doesn't update my table record and didn't return me any MySQL error. Somebody could help me please ?

```
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','Username','Password','Database')
    or die('Could    not connect: ' . mysqli_error($connect));
$handle_source = fopen('http://media.jgoodin.com/dropship/jgi-inventory.csv', 'r');

//updating regular product
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle_source, 500, ",")) !== false)
{
    $VendorSKU = $data[0];
    $onHand = $data[1];

    if ($result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT reference
        FROM ps_product WHERE reference='$VendorSKU'"))
        {
            if ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
                mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE ps_product
                    SET quantity='$onHand'
                    WHERE reference='$VendorSKU'");     

                echo "UPDATE ps_product
                    SET quantity='$onHand'
                    WHERE reference='$VendorSKU'","<br>";
            }   
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
}
fclose($handle_source);
mysqli_close($connect);
```

Comment: Perhaps there is no row where `reference='$VendorSKU'`.

Comment: You're looping through a CSV file and overwriting the $result variable every time.  Only the $result corresponding to the last line is used.  It's possible that the last line being read is blank.

Comment: When it find a record (VendorSKU)  equal to the reference in my table it's making the echo but it doesn't update the table record.

Answer (score 0):

change your update call to:

```
if (!mysqli_query($connect, 'UPDATE ps_product
    SET quantity=' . intval($onHand, 10) . '
    WHERE LOWER(trim(reference))=\'' . strtolower(trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $VendorSKU))) . '\''))
{
    die(mysqli_error($connect));
}
```

also, you can just remove check whether product exists - it is useless

Comment: I remove the check line and changed the update call like above but still not working and didn't have error.

Comment: It's working fine on my local server but doesn't work when hosted.

Comment: @user3476879 why do you think it doesn't work? How do you check db?

Comment: @user3476879 btw for logging purposes add `echo 'Updated: '.mysqli_affected_rows($connect).' rows';` after update query to check whether rows are actually updated

Comment: i can change value in phpmyadmin this script is running on a dedicated server.

Comment: Also added the line echo 'Updated: '.mysqli_affected_rows($connect).' and return me Updated: 0 rows.

Comment: @user3476879 so, this means no rows found to update, there is no such `$VendorSKU` in this table, it either problem with additional spaces or case or are you really sure you have rows to update?

Comment: @user3476879 I've updated code to address possible space/case problems

Comment: yes there are some VendorSKU need to be updated. i change the code you updated and still not working. But i don't understand why the script run perfectly on my local server but not on the hosted one.

Comment: @user3476879 looks like we're using different English languages

Comment: @user3476879 as last solution - dump all UPDATE SQL queries and run them via phpmyadmin to check how many rows are updated by every of them

Comment: Sorry :) my english is not very good. When i run it on Xampp everything working fine. On the dedicated server nothing work.